# How to conditionally split a full name string column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

## Problem

In pandas, I have a dataframe like so:

```
   email    first_name    last_name  full_name  ...(more columns)
   a@a.com  alex          west       NaN        ...
   b@b.com  bill          blue       NaN        ...
   c@c.com  Nan           NaN        mike pound ...
```

And I am trying to conditionally format the dataframe so that the result is as such where I would ultimately drop the full name column:

```
   email    first_name    last_name  full_name  ...(more columns)
   a@a.com  alex          west       NaN        ...
   b@b.com  bill          blue       NaN        ...
   c@c.com  mike          pound      NaN        ...
```

## Partial solution

This is what I have done so far:

```
# create a copy of the raw dataset
names = raw_data

# split the full name into first and last names
names[['First Name', 'Last Name']] = names['Full Name'].loc[names['Full Name'].notna()].str.split(n=1, expand=True)
```

However this results in a dataframe which looks like:

```
   email    first_name    last_name  full_name  ...(more columns)
   a@a.com  NaN           NaN        NaN        ...
   b@b.com  NaN           NaN        NaN        ...
   c@c.com  mike          pound      NaN        ...
```

How can I conditionally apply this? Do I need to use a lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

You need set mask in both sides with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and then create new columns names, e.g. by [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
mask = names['Full Name'].notna()
names.loc[mask, ['First Name', 'Last Name']] = (names.loc[mask, 'Full Name'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)
                                                     .set_axis(['First Name', 'Last Name'], axis=1, inplace=False))

print (names)
     email First Name Last Name   Full Name
0  a@a.com       alex      west         NaN
1  b@b.com       bill      blue         NaN
2  c@c.com       mike     pound  mike pound
```

Or set them by list:

```
mask = names['Full Name'].notna()
df = names.loc[mask, 'Full Name'].str.split(n=1, expand=True)
df.columns = ['First Name','Last Name']
names.loc[mask, ['First Name', 'Last Name']] = df

print (names)

     email First Name Last Name   Full Name
0  a@a.com       alex      west         NaN
1  b@b.com       bill      blue         NaN
2  c@c.com       mike     pound  mike pound
```